# I like to select a img in a div which is within another div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am rather new to Javascript and I have a problem with selecting a div within another div.

I have a DIV called ‘kaartdeck’. Within this DIV there are 78 other div’s for each card individually. Within these div’s there are .jpg files of the cards. Now I want to select one of the cards out of the spread (with the onclick function), but I don’t  get the right syntax for it.

Perhaps this is not a proper approach for this problem. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="kaartdeck" class="symbolonkaart" onclick="showDiv()">
```

This is the way the div’s are generated:

```
//presenting the cards
for (var i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
    document.write("<div id=" + ("kaart" + [i]) + ">" + "<img src='" + (kaart[i].nr +     ".jpg") + "' width='110' height='180' onclick='showDiv()'/></div>");
};
```

This is the showDiv function in the head section (which is not good):

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("kaartdeck").style.display = "block",  divContent = kaartdeck.innerHTML;
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you don't use jQuery in your code, so here is a solution without it which is faster and simpler, more based on your original code.
You have to use event argument's target property to reference the clicked div in code.

You current `showDiv` function has no connection to the clicked div so it can't work. The right solution would be something like this:

```
function showDiv(e) {
   var kaartdeck = document.getElementById("kaartdeck");
   kaartdeck.style.display = "block";
   kaartdeck.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
   return false;
};
```

You will also have to change the HTML generator to look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
  document.write(
    "<div id=" + ("kaart" + [i]) + ">" +
    "<img src='" + (kaart[i].nr + ".jpg") + 
    "' width='110' height='180' onclick='showDiv(event)'/></div>");
};
```

As you can see, I added the `event` parameter there.

You could also pass the value of the `i` loop variable into `showDiv` and then use standard DOM functions to `getElementById("kaart" + i)`.

EDIT:
For older versions of Internet Explorer, the `e.target` reference is not working and is undefined; the right way to get the clicked element is using the `srcElement` property. Simple workaround then is to perform this "hack" in the beginning of the event handler:

```
e.target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it generates the following message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: I have put together a simple JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/v98PM/
Try to check if you don't have something incorrectly written

Comment: I think that it is necessarry to get the i loop into the showDiv function. I've tried this:   var kaartdeck = document.getElementById('<div id=" + ("kaart" + [i]) + ">' ); but that didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using the square brackets around i in the id definition? It should be just "kaart" + i

Comment: Thanks, Mzetko. It works. I added this alert: alert(e.target.src) and this gives the path to the image.

Answer (score 2):

Best to pass a reference to the clicked element like this...

HTML:

```
<div id="kaartdeck" class="symbolonkaart" onclick="showDiv(this)">
```

jQuery:

```
//presenting the cards
for (var i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
  document.write("<div id=" + ("kaart" + [i]) + ">" + "<img src='" + (kaart[i].nr +     ".jpg") + "' width='110' height='180' onclick='showDiv(this)'/></div>");
};

function showDiv(ele) {
 $(ele).css('display': 'block');
 $(ele).html('<p>your html here</p>'); // using jQuery instead of innerHTML
 // ... etc
 return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only thing is that I don't know how to retrieve an image within a div in the $(ele).html row.

Comment: @user3107597 I'm not clear exactly what you want to do. You have a number of cards and when you click on one what exactly do you want to happen? `$(ele).find('img')` inside the showDiv() function should find the image within the clicked div.

Comment: That's what I want. I added: alert($('img').attr("src")); to the code and that returns the name of a jpg file, which is good. The only thing is that it is a jpg from another div (the first div). I can't explain that because the function is working on that other div.

Comment: @user3107597 And if you try $(ele).find('img').attr("src") that should give you the img within the div that you clicked. $('img') will return all img in the DOM

Comment: I deleted the other DIV and now I am getting the first card on the correct DIV, but not the card that is clicked on. It looks like the first DIV is always selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an basic example of selecting a div element: http://jsfiddle.net/j9fzp/
As geedubb has already said you can use `this` For the parameter of `showDiv(this)`. Although another way I think of is using and Canvas (if possible) so there are not so many divs on the page.

Comment: I've tried this solution too. When I'm looking at the control window it seems to work. I also get an Alert. The only thing is that the alert is empty. So, the content of 'divContent' is not presented.